# Gem::InstallError: byebug requires Ruby version >= 2.4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

While commanding"Bundle Install " in git bash,I  am finiding this error "Gem::InstallError: byebug requires Ruby version >= 2.4.0.
An error occurred while installing byebug (11.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '11.1.3' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling."
How can I solve the problem??Need the help badly.

In Gemfile:
  byebugGem

Comment: You need to add more info than an error message. What did you try to resolve this problem? Did you try running the gem install command the error message suggests? If so, what happened? The more information you provide about what you tried, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either upgrade your Ruby version to 2.4.0 or higher, or drop your byebug version down to something that's compatable with your Ruby version.

Comment: How to do that, can you help me out??